# Log4j2.xml configuration file not parsing mapMessage properties

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to pass in a messageMap of variables to log, but when I do so I cannot access them via the %k{key} syntax. However the map is coming through, but as a plain message object. If I print %msg into the console all the vars along with their values are printed.

In the console message I would expect to see the passed %K{ip} value at the end, but it appears that no value is obtained, but the ip string is in the %msg value.

Please look at my code and let me know if I am missing something.
Configuration file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n  %K{argsString} %K{ip} %n%ex{full}%n" />
        </Console>
        <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="durations">
            <ConnectionFactory class="com.lg.log.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
            <Column name="level" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="method" pattern="%K{method}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="arguments" pattern="%K{argsString}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="timestamp" isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="duration" pattern="%K{duration}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="exception" pattern="%ex{full}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="ip" pattern="%K{ip}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="threadIdentifier" pattern="%K{threadID}" isUnicode="false" />
        </JDBC>
        <JDBC name="databaseExceptionsAppender" tableName="exceptions">
            <ConnectionFactory class="com.lg.log.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
            <Column name="level" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="method" pattern="%K{method}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="arguments" pattern="%K{argsString}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="timestamp" isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="exception" pattern="%K{exception}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="ip" pattern="%K{ip}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="threadIdentifier" pattern="%K{threadID}" isUnicode="false" />
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.lg.log.ExceptionLoggerAspect" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseExceptionsAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.lg.log.DurationLoggingAspect" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="ExceptionLoggerAspect"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Java code:

```
private void logException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e)  {
    Map<String, String> myMessageMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        myMessageMap.put("ip", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().toString());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        myMessageMap.put("ip", "UNKNOWN");
    }
    if (joinPoint.getTarget() != null) {
        myMessageMap.put("method", joinPoint.getTarget().toString() + '.' + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    } else {
        myMessageMap.put("method", joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
    myMessageMap.put("threadID", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()));
    myMessageMap.put("exception", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    myMessageMap.put("argsString", getArgumentsAsText(joinPoint));
    logger.error(new MapMessage(myMessageMap));
}
```

Console Output:

```
15:23:44.705 [main] ERROR com.lg.log.ExceptionLoggerAspect - argsString="" exception="java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
" ip="192.168.0.85" method="com.lg.Test" threadID="1"
```

LOG4J2 Dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: which `log4j2` version you are using ? can you post your `log4j2` dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **log4j2 version 2.9**, you have to use `org.apache.logging.log4j.message.StringMapMessage` instead of `org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MapMessage` for string only values.

`StringMapMessage` is same as `MapMessage` before version 2.9 as per [JavaDcos](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/StringMapMessage.html).

Also, `MapMessage` is of generic type now, the way you are using you should be receiving some warnings.